# Rotary Phones vs Pushbutton -- why did we ever have rotary?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, telecommunication

I remember when we first got pushbutton phones -- I would say user experience is literally ten times better -- if you used a rotary phone extensively as part of your job, you would rapidly develop a callous on your dialing finger. Of course, you also push the same number (we still use the term dial, at least some people do) maybe ten times faster than a dial.

My question is, why was a dial ever used? Could not something like a pushbutton phone have been developed much sooner? What is the idea behind the dial "UI"?

Note that I know something about computer history, how incredibly hard it used to be, for example, to store a byte of memory using mercury delay lines -- so if I suggest that a musical note be sent (as maybe push button phones did it) instead of N pulses for the integer N I can guess that this is much easier said than done.

Comment: We have to walk before we run.  What seems simple now, was a major engineering event then.  I watched Ghostbuster last night and laughed at the portable phones.  And anyone who used the phones a lot, used a pencil to dial.

Comment: Because this system predates modern electronics by a safe margin of 30 years. So yes simple now not simple then.

Comment: If you look into how both works, you'll see rotary is easier. Counting pulses is easier than mixing frequencies.

Comment: There's still some demand of rotary dial phones. Otherwise they would be vanished. Select your favourite https://freeappsforme.com/rotary-dialer-apps/

Comment: Before I say Get Offa My Lawn Young Punks, I'll suggest as others have, that you spend a little time looking up the history of electromechanical devices prior to the commercialization of transistors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotary phones were controlled by sending pulses down the line.  These pulses were the equivalent of hanging up the phone quickly - hence what you see in old movies and TV shows when they quickly tap the hang-up mechanism to get the operator.  In the final versions of rotary phones, you could "dial" by quickly pressing down the hang-up button the right number of times for each number.  All the rotary mechanism did was send the equivalent of a hang-up press quickly in succession the right number of times.

So why didn't tones work?  Because mechanical relays won't send tones, the phones system listeners wouldn't accept tones, and because in general technology has to be invented before it works.  You might as well ask why Mr. Bell didn't invent cell phones straight off.

Comment: :) I was about to ask the same question.

Comment: Is that why they tap the phone? I always just assumed it was a "turning it on and off again" to see if phone was online or not.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is simple - the timing in the evaluation of technology. The required technology to make touchtone signal possible, Dual-tone multi-frequency signaling (DTMF), wasn't developed/introduced by Bell System until 1963, while the rotary technology was made available in 1892 by the American inventor Almon Brown Strowger. Even then, the first dial pad with finger holes wasn't introduced until about 1904 (28 years after the first telephone was invented), and then been adopted and used in the telephone service since 1919.

The predator of DTMF was multi-frequency signaling (MF), which is a type of signaling that was introduced after World War II. It uses a combination of audible tones for address (telephone number) transport and supervision signaling on trunk lines between central offices. The signaling is sent in-band over the same channel as the bearer channel used for voice traffic.

The later developed DTMF technology uses the same fundamental principle but was used primarily for signaling address information and control signals from a user's telephone to the wire centers Class-5 switch.

[https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/DTMF#:~:text=DTMF%2C%20developed%20by%20Bell%20System%2C%20was%20introduced%20for,systems%20DTMF%20was%20initially%20developed%20using%20analog%20electronics](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/DTMF#:%7E:text=DTMF%2C%20developed%20by%20Bell%20System%2C%20was%20introduced%20for,systems%20DTMF%20was%20initially%20developed%20using%20analog%20electronics).

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_dial#:~:text=The%20first%20patent%20for%20a%20rotary%20dial%20was,finger%20wheel%20was%20not%20introduced%20until%20about%201904](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_dial#:%7E:text=The%20first%20patent%20for%20a%20rotary%20dial%20was,finger%20wheel%20was%20not%20introduced%20until%20about%201904).

Comment: interesting use of "predator" -- i know you meant, "the thing that pre-dates" but i am not sure this is really a meaning, all i can find is the conventional meaning, the one about one animal eating another.

Answer (score 1):

Because a spring loaded mechanism with controlled spacing was (relatively) easy with the technology and materials of the time.

The plastics and conductive plastics for the push-buttons we use now would not have been possible.

Then consider the control of the pulses from the push-buttons and convering to the info needed to make the “number” work with the correct spacing.  If you waited too long when dialling using an old phone it would cancel the number.

Comment: The pushbutton is called "touch tone" -- what would have prevented transmitting a sequence of notes (is that basically what touch tone phones do?) instead of, it sounds like, pulses, N pulses for a given integer N? It seems like some musical device that had no  electronics could have generated the tone -- perhaps decoding the tone on the other end would have been the hard part. I know how hard "easy" things are to do -- I have read about mercury delay memory, immense amount of work to store like a byte.

Comment: @releseabe if you ever used modems and set the intervals etc then you would know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did use a modem but i do not recall setting intervals.

Comment: @releseabe lack of transistors. Technology bases change. Classic example it seems like science fiction that a tv could change a channel instantaneously. But yes the old analog tvs could change channels mid frame if needed. So today the technology of touch tone is indeed easier than the rotary clicks because you get it essentially free of charge but not so in early 1900